Low Validation and Test Accuracy with Random Forest on ECG Data
I'm working on a project involving ECG data classification using a Random Forest model. Unfortunately, my model's performance is significantly lower than expected, and I'm struggling to understand why.
Here are the details:
my data organisation:

each folder for classes contains csv file ( 13 columns)
Validation Accuracy: 0.22705314009661837  
Test Accuracy: 0.1746987951807229  

As you can see, the performance metrics are quite poor. Here is the code I used to train and evaluate the model:
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def load_data(folder):
    X = []
    Y = []
    classes = [d for d in os.listdir(folder) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder, d))]
    
    for class_name in classes:
        class_path = os.path.join(folder, class_name)
        for file_name in os.listdir(class_path):
            if file_name.endswith('.csv'):
                file_path = os.path.join(class_path, file_name)
                try:
                    data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
                    X.append(data.values)  # Ajouter les données du fichier
                    Y.append(class_name)   # Ajouter le nom de la classe pour ce fichier
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error reading {file_path}: {e}")
    
    return X, Y
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
"""
def load_data(folder, samples_per_class=250):
    X = []
    Y = []
    classes = [d for d in os.listdir(folder) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder, d))]
    
    for class_name in classes:
        class_path = os.path.join(folder, class_name)
        files = [f for f in os.listdir(class_path) if f.endswith('.csv')]
        files_to_load = min(samples_per_class, len(files))
        selected_files = np.random.choice(files, size=files_to_load, replace=False)
        for file_name in selected_files:
            file_path = os.path.join(class_path, file_name)
            try:
                data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
                X.append(data.iloc[:, 1:].values)  # Ajouter les données du fichier
                Y.append(class_name)   # Ajouter le nom de la classe pour ce fichier
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error reading {file_path}: {e}")
    
    return X, Y
    """
# y encoder
def encode_labels(y_train, y_valid, y_test):
    ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
    y_train = np.array(y_train).reshape(-1, 1)
    y_valid = np.array(y_valid).reshape(-1, 1)
    y_test = np.array(y_test).reshape(-1, 1)
    y_train_enc = ohe.fit_transform(y_train)
    y_valid_enc = ohe.transform(y_valid)
    y_test_enc = ohe.transform(y_test)
    return y_train_enc, y_valid_enc, y_test_enc, ohe

print("loading data")
# Charger les données
X_train, y_train = load_data(trainFolder)
X_valid, y_valid = load_data(validFolder)
X_test, y_test = load_data(testFolder)

print("encoding labels")
# Encoder les étiquettes de classe
y_train, y_valid, y_test, ohe = encode_labels(y_train, y_valid, y_test)

# Convertir les listes en arrays NumPy si nécessaire
X_train = np.array(X_train)
X_valid = np.array(X_valid)
X_test = np.array(X_test)

# Flatten the target labels if they are one-hot encoded
y_train_flat = y_train.argmax(axis=1)
y_valid_flat = y_valid.argmax(axis=1)
y_test_flat = y_test.argmax(axis=1)



save_args = {
    'X_train': X_train.astype('float32'),
    'X_valid': X_valid.astype('float32'),
    'X_test':  X_test.astype('float32'),
    'y_train': y_train_flat.astype('float32'), 
    'y_valid': y_valid_flat.astype('float32'),
    'y_test':  y_test_flat.astype('float32')
}


print("training")
# Flatten the feature data
X_train_2d = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], -1)
X_valid_2d = X_valid.reshape(X_valid.shape[0], -1)
X_test_2d = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], -1)

# Initialize and train the Random Forest classifier
rf_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, criterion="gini",random_state=42)
rf_classifier.fit(X_train_2d, y_train_flat)

# Make predictions on the validation set
valid_predictions = rf_classifier.predict(X_valid_2d)

# Evaluate accuracy on the validation set
valid_accuracy = accuracy_score(y_valid_flat, valid_predictions)
print("Validation Accuracy:", valid_accuracy)

# Confusion matrix for validation set
valid_conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_valid_flat, valid_predictions)
print("Validation Confusion Matrix:\n", valid_conf_matrix)

# Make predictions on the test set
test_predictions = rf_classifier.predict(X_test_2d)

# Evaluate accuracy on the test set
test_accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test_flat, test_predictions)
print("Test Accuracy:", test_accuracy)

# Confusion matrix for test set
test_conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test_flat, test_predictions)
print("Test Confusion Matrix:\n", test_conf_matrix)

How to improve the performance of my Random Forest model on this ECG dataset?

Post your question on Code Review for performance improvement.
